# Userdictionary.Word.APP_ID

Tags: android

I am implementing a content provider in Android using UserDictionary.

I have inserted rows in the following manner

```
    public void insertData(String text){

    Log.d(TAG, "App Name: "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    mNewValues = new ContentValues();
    mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, getResources().getString(R.string.locale));
    mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, text);
    mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY, "100");

    mNewUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues);

    getInsertedData();

}
```

The reading of the dictionary is done like this

```
    public void getInsertedData(){

    mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,  // The content URI of the words table
            mProjection,                       // The columns to return for each row
            null,                   // Either null, or the word the user entered
            null,
            null);     

    if (null == mCursor) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor Null");
    } else if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {


        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor Empty");

    } else {

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){
               do{
                  String word = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD));
                  String appName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID));


               }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            mCursor.close();
    }

}
```

But when I am logging the output of UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID (as fetched from cursor object) it gives me a value  0 (zero). The UserDictionary.Words.WORD gives the correct output that is the words that has been entered.

My Question is that why is the UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID giving a value of 0 and how do I get the application name then ?

Comment: hello soumya..have u found any solution becoz i also get app id 0